# mongoose await promise error

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

I am trying to use await while querying for a collection but I can't run it. I don't see the mistake

```
router.route('/errors')
    .post((req, res) => {
        const envirementName = getProjectEnv(getErrorLocation(req.body.error));

        let envCollection = await EnvirementProjectsCollection.findOne({envirementName}).exec();
        console.log(envCollection);
    });
```

It crashes with -

```
let envCollection = await EnvirementProjectsCollection.findOne({envirementName}).exec();
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:588:28)
```

From what I saw the exec() function of the query will return a promise which I want to await for. Currently I can't find the mistake. I would be glad for some explanation and help with what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: await can only be used inside an `async` function

Comment: Your syntax is invalid. You have a trailing `)`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I edited it maybe a typo while copying the error.

Comment: `maybe a typo` Either it is or it isn't - check your original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you haven't used async keyword before the function.

Try with this Code.

Hope this answer is helpfull to you.

```
router.route('/errors')
    .post(async (req, res) => {
        const envirementName = getProjectEnv(getErrorLocation(req.body.error));

        let envCollection = await EnvirementProjectsCollection.findOne({envirementName}).exec();
        console.log(envCollection);
    });
```